# How to create navigation tabbar each tab has each stack history

Tags: android, react-native, navigation, expo

I want to below behivor in my expo (react native)app.

- App always appear tabbar on top of app.
- tabbar have multiple tab like "HOME", "ABOUT", "Settings".
- Home have any button(link) for moving to page.
- when user push any button(Link), move to that page and appear stack navigation bar below tabbar.
- when user push back button of device or stack navigation bar, move to previous page of stack. (this stack don't change when user push back button of stack navigation bar of other tab).

How can I do?

And I want to use that code on react-native-web if it can use.

Comment: You'll need to nest stack navigators inside tab navigator.

Comment: which library should I use? react-navigation or react-navigation-flux, react-router-navigation

Comment: I use react-navigation and don't have any idea about the others

Comment: Thank you for your advice. react-navigation may best things.